# Error loading JavaScript file in EPiServer module after upgrading from .NET 5 to .NET 6

Tags: module, .net-6.0, episerver, clientresource

I recently updated my Episerver project's custom module from .NET 5 to .NET 6. In the previous version, the project used Episerver 12.9.0, but after the upgrade, it now uses Episerver 12.19.0.

However, after completing the upgrade, I encountered an error indicating that the JavaScript file within my module cannot be found. In the project, the file was located in modules_protected[Module Name][Version]\ClientResources\scripts\editors folder. But when I load the project, it is looking for the file at [Root]/ClientResources/ClientResources/scripts/editors/.

I attempted to modify the module configuration to correct the file path, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Could anyone please help me resolve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After carefully examining the files in the root folder, I was able to identify the cause of the error. I noticed that there was a copy of the module.config file present. This was the reason behind the error being thrown.